# Create "grid" of items in Swift that have independent variables?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm looking to create a 10x10 "grid" of items, each with their own set of variables, that can be accessed (and edited) via incrementing a number up and down.  Essentially choosing an item by it's location in the grid.  I'm still new-ish to Swift; would this be accomplished by using a struct to create the properties of each item, a method within the struct to add it to a dictionary, and then an array of dictionaries to hold the values and tie them to a sequential order?  For access/editing, I could then tie either the array location to the order of images in the grid or the tag number of an object and have the user increment numbers to select which image to edit?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a class, not a struct, as you want to edit the properties. Put that in an Array of Array of that class. That should work. `Array<Array<YourClass>>()` or `[[YourClass]]()`. Let me know if that doesn’t work.

Comment: Interesting; thanks! What would be the advantage to using a 2d or 3d array instead of a dictionary?  Is it speed as the arrays are already in sequential order?

Comment: You said you want to do a 10 by 10 matrix. Dictionaries don’t offer any help here. Yes, you can put a “1”,”data” pair in, but this comes out of the box with arrays. Speed is no concern for a 10 x 10 array

Comment: Makes sense.  How would you then use a set of buttons to select an 'active' array entry to edit?  I've been trying indexOf() without success; my thought was to have the active array be selected by incrementing the index value of the array, then have UI connections to edit the data within that 'selected' array of an array.

Comment: I would create a little view with 10x10 boxes allowing the user to select the right box. Box colour & shape could represent the data. Should be feasible with fingers even on a small screen.  But maybe that doesn’t match your needs? I don’t know what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd want a 2-D array of some protocol conforming objects that behave the way you want

```
protocol GridItemType {
   // your grid item variables and methods
}
```

and then

```
var Grid: [[GridItemType]]
```

could be your grid (a 2D array).

You could just represent your index in the grid with a row and column number. To increment by column, you could just increase the column number until you reach the end of a row, and then increment the row. You can do something similar to increment by row.